# Print prime numbers between 0 and 100

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print all prime number between 0 and 100, but when executing this code the browser's tab just outputs nothing!!

```
    for(var i = 2; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var prime = [];
        for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            var p = i % j;
        }
        if(p != 0) prime.push(i);
            else continue;
    }

    for(var k = 0; k < prime.length; k++)
    {
        document.writeln(prime[k], "<br>");
    }
```

Comment: Your code is wrong... Look at the if... look at where your array is defined.

Comment: The `else continue` is completely redundant.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://codility.com/media/train/8-PrimeNumbers.pdf

Comment: And `for ... {document.writeln(prime[k], "<br>")}` can be `document.writeln(prime.join('<br>'))` and *j* only needs to go half way, i.e. `j <= i/2`. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. I have also optimise the code (you only need to check upto sqrt(i) ).

```
 var prime = [];
 prime.push(2); //smallest prime
 var flag = 0; 
 for(var i = 3; i < 100; i=i+2)   //skip all even no
    {            
      for(var j = 3; j*j <= i; j=j+2)   //check by upto sqrt(i), skip all even no
        {                          
          if(i % j == 0) {
              flag = 0;break;       //not a prime, break
            }  
          flag = 1;      
        }
      if (flag == 1) prime.push(i);  //prime, add to answer
    }

    for(var k = 0; k < prime.length; k++)
    {
        document.writeln(prime[k], "<br>");
    }
```

Comment: If you already have a list of primes below `i`, you can just check to see if any of those divide `i`.

Comment: Optimised? Initialise prime as `[2]`, skip all even numbers greater than 2 and start at 3, so `i+=2` and `j=3; j*j<=i; j+=2`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Because you blank your list of primes EVERY loop cycle, move it outside the for loop

Comment: if condition needs to be inside the loop as well

Comment: There is another problem there. The inner loop checks against `i % 0` (division by 0) and `i % 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your variable prime outside of your loop

This is the code you have re-written

```
var prime = [];
for(var i = 2; i < 100; i++)
{

    for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        var p = i % j;
    }
    if(p != 0) prime.push(i);
        else continue;
}

for(var k = 0; k < prime.length; k++)
{
    document.writeln(prime[k], "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the sieve of Eratosthenes.
The following code should do what you wanted.

```
var prime = Array(101).fill(true);
for (var i = 2; i < 100; ++i){
  if (prime[i]){
    document.writeln(i, "<br>");
    for (var j = i*i; j < 100; j += i){
      prime[j] = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Or since it's only up to 100 you could just manually type the list (but, hey where's the learning if you do it that way?).

Answer (score 0):

(1) Move prime outside the for loop, (2) start j at 2 and end when j < i, (3) check when p == 0 with a boolean flag and break inner loop.

```
var prime = []; //put prime out here so it does not reassign
for(var i = 2; i < 100; i++)
{

    var isPrime = true; 
    for(var j = 2; j < i; j++) //start j at 2
    {
        var p = i % j;
        if(p == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime) prime.push(i); 
}

for(var k = 0; k < prime.length; k++)
{
    document.writeln(prime[k], "<br>");
}
```